# QChart take all ressources from my CPU Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QChart in my application that receives information in real time.
The chart is also scrolling to the left every 100 millisecond with the help of a timer. This chart works well but the problem is that in two minutes, my application is taking all ressources from my CPU and my computer becomes very slow.

Does anyone already had this problem and how did you solve it ?

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58802 that's a bug in qchart

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you if there is another way to do it ?

Comment: you can delete your series every time and then plot it again with new value

Comment: and if you want to feel no pain, stop using qchart. it`s very raw and poor module, which using too much cpu and memory resources. my advise - use qcustomplot or qwt. Both of them much better that qchart

Comment: I think that is what I'll do.